# Pyglet: control audio balance (panning)

Tags: audio, pyglet

I am looking for a way to control the balance of a sound (left-right) with Pyglet.

I am aware of the 3D positioning system, but what I really want is just control the panning (something like -1:left <--> 1:right), and the 3D system is quite counter-productive in that context (or maybe I am missing something).

If not with Pyglet, could you suggest any other python library allowing this?

(I've been looking at many, but without success).

It seems like a pretty straightforward task to ask to a sound engine, but I am not able to figure it out...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that `pygame` handles that.

The sound engine in `pygame` is based on `sdl_mixer`, which allows the use of channels, of which you can control the left and right volume separetely.

It is not `pyglet`... But... `pygame` seems to be included in [`Cocos2D`](http://www.cocos2d.org) which is built on `pyglet`...